# Saving SMTP password for later use, without hash

Tags: php, mysql, sql, smtp, phpmailer

I created a PHP application where I have a settings panel, where the user has to provide some data, necessary for the application to work. There are fields regarding SMTP settings, that the user will provide, so that the application can send confirmation emails to customers when t.

In order to do that i save the information provided in the database, one of the required fields is SMTP Password, which i need to save in a raw state, without any hashing. I need it this way because PHPMailer needs the password as it is, not a hash.

I am worried about how secure this method is, because i don't want to save it in plain text, but i also need it this way in order to send emails.

I need some advice regarding this issue.

PS: I forgot to mention that i use XAMPP to develop the application.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't save it in the database. Save it inside a .env file and store it 1 level up from your web root then use your middleware to access the .env.

Comment: @Lulceltech How is that better? If someone breaks into the server, they can read the `.env` file just as easily as accessing the DB.

Comment: @Barmar that assumes you poorly secure your servers. Storing credentials like that 1 level up from your web root is the industry standard. If you want to get more secure you can AES encrypt the password and store it with the IV inside the database as well as then storing the decryption key 1 level up from web root. If they can break into your web server through you have bigger concerns then them getting your email password.

Comment: @Lulceltech The whole reason for storing hashed passwords in the first place is because you assume there's a vulnerability that allows someone to break in to the server. It doesn't mean you've secured your servers poorly, no one knows all the vulnerabilities.

Comment: If you secure your server properly the only way you should be able to access anything above your web root is with Physical access to the server. No security is perfect, but this is the industry standard for a reason.

Comment: Do you need to store passwords for individual user emails or for 1 application email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never store plain text passwords in the database. As other commenters have noted, .env configuration files above the web root are a standard approach. However, the approach you take depends on how your app is hosted. For example, if you are hosting the app on AWS, the recommended approach is to store the credentials as environment variables that can be accessed like so:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Host = $_SERVER['SES_HOST'];
    $mail->Username = $_SERVER['SES_USERNAME'];
    $mail->Password = $_SERVER['SES_PASSWORD'];
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

The same approach can be taken using a .env file. Or if you are using Apache, you could add the variables to the httpd.conf file as shown below, and then access them by referencing the $_SERVER global:

```
SetEnv SES_PASSWORD strongpassword123
```

Since you mentioned you are using XAMPP (so Apache), open the Apache config and modify the httpd.conf file and add the SetEnv line above to the bottom of that file. After restarting the Apache service, you will be able to reference your value using $_SERVER['var_name'].